# Can the Source Code in TFS Be Encrypted?

Tags: security, encryption, tfs

I am a newbie on team foundation server 2012. The sql server stores changesets of the code in the db. Which tables are those exactly ? Is it possible to encrypt this/the sourcecode in the db?

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt the entire TFS database using SQL Server TDE (transparent data encryption) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx

Comment: would this work in conjunction with TFS? I mean all the functionality , checking in , get latest would still work when I would use this?

Comment: Correct, TDE is transparent to TFS and is the recommended way to encrypt TFS data.

Comment: Hi Dylan, does TDE support SQL Servers that run on a on-premises vm running on VMware/Hyper-V? And is the SQL Server Enterprise edition required for using this feature?